# Why is my dynamic Gatsby page not working

Tags: node.js, regex, gatsby, server-side-rendering

I'm trying to create dynamic pages based on a database that grows by the minute. Therefor it isn't an option to use `createPage` and build several times a day.

I'm using `onCreatePage` here to create pages which works fine for my first route, but when I try to make an English route somehow it doesn't work.

`gatby-node.js`:

```
exports.onCreatePage = async ({ page, actions: { createPage } }) => {
  if (page.path.match(/^\/listing/)) {
    page.matchPath = '/listing/:id'
    createPage(page)
  }

  if (page.path.match(/^\/en\/listing/)) {
    page.matchPath = '/en/listing/:id'
    createPage(page)
  }
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve here is getting 2 dynamic routes like:

- localhost:8000/listing/123 (this one works)
- localhost:8000/en/listing/123 (this one doesn't work)

My `pages` folder looks like this:

```
pages
---listing.tsx
---en/
------listing.tsx
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong here?

--

P.S. I want to use SSR (available since Gatsby v4) by using the `getServerData()` in the templates for these pages. Will that work together with pages created dynamically with `onCreatePage` or is there a better approach?

Comment: If you reverse the condition (first using the `en`), does the work in the opposite way (the `en/listing/123` is created but the `listing/123` doesn't)?

Comment: @FerranBuireu no even when I'm only using the `/en/listing/:id` and comment out `/listing/:id` it's still not working ☹️ I did test my regex using https://regexr.com/ and that looks fine unless there's something I'm missing here...

Answer (score 0):

According to what we've discussed in the comment section: the fact that the `/en/` path is never created, hence is not entering the following condition:

```
  if (page.path.match(/^\/en\/listing/)) {
    page.matchPath = '/en/listing/:id'
    createPage(page)
  }
```

Points me to think that the issue is on your [`createPages`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/config-files/gatsby-node/#createPages) API rather than [`onCreatePage`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/config-files/gatsby-node/#onCreatePage), which means that your english page is not even created.

Keep in mind that `onCreatePage` API is a callback called when a page is created, so it's triggered after `createPages`.

If you add a `console.log(page.path)` you shouldn't see the English page in the IDE/text editor console so try debugging how are you creating the `/en/` route because it seems that `onCreatePage` doesn't have any problem.